# Add AppIcon for Xcode (Ipad Pro App Icon)

Tags: ios, icons, assets

Hi I have made Ipad pro icon (1x 83.5 and 2x 167) and named them (Icon-84.pnp and Icon-84@2x.png). But when I copied to my assets folder. There is no option to choose 1x and 2x (only 2x as pic). How to add these appIcon proper way? Any help is much appreciate! Thanks

[image]

Comment: The iPad pro only requires a @2x icon since it was only released with a retina screen.

Comment: just notice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPad Pro doesn't need a 1x icon asset at all.